# ConTeXt: Relative path for figures using externalfigures

Tags: floats, context, directory

## Background

A wiki page, written in Markdown, is run through pandoc to produce a .tex file for ConTeXT. The wiki page makes references to images that are located in a path relative to the page itself. For example, the wiki page is:

```
 http://wiki.server.com/xwiki/bin/view/Clients/Projects/CR1234567
```

When the wiki page is exported, the references to the images resemble:

```
<img src="/xwiki/bin/download/Clients/Projects/CR123457/WebHome/image.svg"/>
```

Then pandoc transforms the `.html` file to `.tex` as:

```
{\externalfigure[/xwiki/bin/download/Clients/Projects/CR1234567/WebHome/image.svg]}
```

The images can be exported into that particular directory relative to a parent "images" directory. The hierarchy resembles:

```
./
./images/
./images/xwiki/bin/download/Clients/Projects/CR1234567/WebHome/
```

Where `./` is the directory wherein ConTeXt runs.

## Problem

It appears as though `externalfigure`s cannot use [relative paths](http://ospublish.constantvzw.org/sources/vj10/interior-tex-context/environ.tex).

## Code

The figures are setup as follows:

```
\setupexternalfigures[
  order={svg, pdf, png, jpg},
  factor=fit,
  maxwidth=\textwidth,
  maxheight=\pageheight,
  directory={images},
]
```

The following directory option was also tried without success:

```
  directory={images, images/xwiki/bin/download/Clients/Projects/CR123457/WebHome},
```

## Invocation

None of the following ConTeXt invocations worked (`--trackers=graphics.conversion` revealed no obvious problems):

```
context --path=styles main.tex
context --path=styles,images main.tex
context --path=styles,images\xwiki\bin\download\Clients\Projects\CR1234567\WebHome main.tex
context --path=styles,images/xwiki/bin/download/Clients/Projects/CR1234567/WebHome main.tex
```

## Question

Can ConTeXt include an external figure that is referenced using a relative path? If so, how?

## Environment

Note that pandoc generates `externalfigures` rather than `useexternalfigures`.

- ConTeXt MKIV 2018.01.04 17:37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your question is posed in such a way that it is impossible for me to reproduce your exact setup and error.

> It appears as though externalfigures cannot use relative paths.

Not true.  This works for me in TL 2017 and standalone on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
\starttext
\externalfigure[../../usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.png]
\stoptext
```

```
\setupexternalfigures[directory={../../usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/}]
\starttext
\externalfigure[example-image-a.png]
\stoptext
```

Something else must be wrong.

Note that the `externalfigure` starts with an absolute path, `/xwiki`. This will have to change. You can either try writing a pandoc filter, or use a program such as `sed` to change the path to a relative directory, such as:

```
sed -i "s/\/xwiki/.\/images/g" %TEX%
```

Comment: Ah! Now I get your problem.  It seems that this is a problem of the reader because the pandoc ConTeXt writer does not touch the image path in any way.  I guess the same issue would appear with other writers.

Comment: You could try with one of their [official Windows builds](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/jgm/pandoc/build/artifacts) and if it still crashes, file an issue.

Comment: My changes are not merged yet but if their builds also crash it is definitely not my fault ;)